# Make a div responsive to another div

Tags: html, css

I've got the below div structure. How do I make `.canvasEl` be responsive to `.vgWrapper`?

example: 
Assume `.vgWrapper` width & height is 200px, 
and `.canvasEl` width & height is 100px.
NOW
when the width & height of `.vgWrapper` is changed to 100px, `.canvasEl` width & height should be 50px.

So the size of `.canvasEl` should automatically change depending on the size of  `.vgWrapper`. Here is a [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/umoyhzjv/)

```
<div class="outerWrapper">
    <div class="vgWrapper">
        <div class="imgWrapper">
            <div class="imgHolder">
                <div class="imgHolderInner">
                    <div class="imgDiv">
                        <canvas class="canvasEl"></canvas> // should resize propotionaltely when .vgWrapper size is chnaged 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bgWrapper">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Either manually via media queries or using percentage based width and height (with a little javascript to help with the height if necessary)? What have you tried?

Comment: @JohnDevelops thanks. I tried to do it using fixed with to the parent div (`outerWrapper`) and using position relative and absolute as per the fiddle. But did was not successful.

Comment: Ive played with the fiddle and posted a suggested solution @Beki

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with your code that prevent the canvas size from being changed.

1. your `.outerWrapper` class has a fixed `width` and `height` of `200px` so that will not change even if the window is resized.
2. your `.canvasEl` class occupies 100% of the width and height of its container ie. `.imgDiv`, which has a width and height of 127px and 146px respectively and is no way related to `.outerWrapper`.

In order to make it work I have used fluid layout ie. width and height in percentages.

```css
.outerWrapper{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; /*when chnaged, .canvasEl should resize accordingly*/
    height: 100%; /*when chnaged, .canvasEl should resize accordingly*/
    background-color: lime;
}
.vgWrapper{
 position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.imgWrapper{
 position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}
.bgWrapper{
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.imgDiv{
 margin: 0px; 
 left: auto; 
 top: auto; 
 /*width: 127px;*/
 /*height: 146px;*/
 overflow: hidden; 
 position: relative;
}
.imgHolder{
 position: absolute;
}
.imgHolderInner{
 position: relative;
}
.canvasEl{
 position:relative;
    width:50%; /*computed with respect to its container*/
    height: 50%; /* computed with respect to its container*/
    background-color: #f60;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerWrapper">
 <div class="vgWrapper">
  <div class="imgWrapper">
   <div class="imgHolder">
    <div class="imgHolderInner">
     <div class="imgDiv">
                        <canvas class="canvasEl"></canvas> // should resize propotionaltely when .vgWrapper size is chnaged 
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bgWrapper">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. Why can't the scaling be done to `imgDiv`? and have 100% to `canvasEl`?

Comment: sorry i don't understand, could you please elaborate? what is is that you are trying now?

Answer (score 0):

**Not need javascript to do this, css media queries is there for you**. I check your code and it depends on the width `.imgDiv`. So when you do your queries, you must work on `.imgDiv`. You should change its width, if do not do this, it will be 100% of `.imgDiv` width.
Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umoyhzjv/3/)

Comment: thanks. WHat you're saying is correct. I tried to make the height and width of ` imgDiv` 100% to the parent but I was not able to get it working. The fiddle is where I'm right now.

Comment: Using % based values should remove the need to set things manually via media queries.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going for something like this to avoid manually setting media queries, assuming you are happy to run some Javascript or JQuery to set the height or find a better CSS solution for height etc.

Width is simple and you don't need to mess with the positioning, assuming I understand your requirements correctly, please see this updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/umoyhzjv/2/

I have simply set the canvas wrapper to 50% width and set the height as half the parents height. You can add $(window).resize() to trigger the code to re-run if this is intended to be interactive etc.

I set the outerWrapper to be % so it is easy to see in the fiddle, just move the page divider to make it scale.

```
.outerWrapper{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%; /*when chnaged, .canvasEl should resize accordingly*/
    height: 50%; /*when chnaged, .canvasEl should resize accordingly*/
    background-color: lime;
}
.vgWrapper{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.imgWrapper{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.bgWrapper{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.imgDiv{
    margin: 0px; 
    width: 50%; 
    height: 50%; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
.canvasEl{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f60;
}
```

Comment: :) looks good. Let me try to incorporate your suggestion to my code and see how it goes.

Comment: This should be the cleanest was to re-produce your idea without messy media queries or position:absolutes.

Comment: @Beki, how are you getting on, any closer?